# Bind9 Master Slave replication

Tags: bind, master-slave

I have Bind9 on Debian for NS1 and NS2
They are two virtual machines.

I create a file /etc/bind/zones/db.domain.com
Then I have to add this to the /etc/bind/named.conf.local

> zone "domain.com" {
>           type master;
>           file "/etc/bind/zones/db.domain.com";
>           allow-transfer { THE.IP.OF.NS2; }; 
>           allow-update { none; }; };

Then when I do a reload I it works on NS1, but Have to go into NS2 and also change the /etc/bind/named.conf.local

> zone "domain.com" {
>           type slave;
>           file "/etc/bind/zones/db.domain.com";
>           masters { THE.IP.OF.NS1; };
>           allow-transfer { none; }; };

From now on when I do a reload/restart on NS1 it replicates the /etc/bind/zones/db.domain.com to NS2.

Is there a way to repilcate the content of /etc/bind/named.conf.local to the Slave, so I dont have to add every time the new domains on ns2 by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably do it with something like puppet or chef (etc) but it's not a simple case of copying a file, or a few stanzas of code, it's different code on each side.

Comment: I meant is there any functions that I might dont know that would repilcate the named.conf.local to te slave? Like an option that I would have to add to the named.conf.options ?? or something?

Comment: None that I've ever heard of, it would certainly be non trivial to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with BIND provided tools.
You will need to implement this in you configuration management system yourself.